# Monitor Youtube iFrame player state in Android

Tags: android, iframe, webview, youtube-api

How to monitor player state in youtube iframe . I need to monitor when player is in buffering state. Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On android if you use Youtube Player Api instead of Iframe you can easily get all callbacks

Check https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer

Comment: taranmeet i have gone through Youtube player Api but my requirements is to run video on all resolution dynamic with player.setPlaybackQuality() but youtube player api doesnt supports that.